# Find and replace @ mentions using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse strings to find and replace @ mentions.

Here is a sample string:

`Hi @jordan123 and @jordan have a good day`

I want to find and replace `@jordan` with `@jordananderson` without modifying `@jordan123`

I used this regex to find a list of all of the mentions in the string:

```
let string = 'Hi @jordan123 and @jordan have a good day'
let result = string.match(/\B\@\w\w+\b/g);
```

that returns:

`['@jordan123', '@jordan']`

But I can't figure out how to continue and complete the replacement.

Valid characters for the username are `alphanumeric` and always start with the `@` symbol.

So it also needs to work for strings like this:

`Hi @jordan123 and @jordan!! have a good day`

And this

`Hi @jordan123! and !@jordan/|:!! have a good day`

My goal is to write a function like this:

`replaceUsername(string, oldUsername, newUsername)`

Comment: If the valid characters are `alphanumeric`, why is `@jordan123` not valid to be replaced?

Comment: @Taplar I want to replace only `@jordan` another use case would be if I wanted to find and replace `@jordan123`

Comment: If you want to replace jordan and not jordan123 then you are after matching `[a-zA-Z]`, which does not include numbers.

Comment: I need the function to work with and without numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need `\b`, which matches a word boundary:

The regex: `@jordan\b` will match:

Hi @jordan123 and **@jordan**!! have a good day

Hi @jordan123! and !**@jordan**/|:!! have a good day

To build this regex, just build it like a string; don't forget to sanitize the input if it's from the user.

`var reg = new RegExp("@" + toReplace + "\\b")`

Comment: How would I replace @jordan123 ? Numbers are also valid for the username

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. This works fine with numbers as well. Just instead of using `@jordan\b`, use `@jordan123\b` to replace jordan123

Comment: I assume with this @jordan123\b so essentially username + \b. B as in, this is the boundary, You shall not pass.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you have one string of a found value, and a larger string with many values, including the found value, you can use methods such as split, replace, indexOf and substring etc to replace it

The problem here is how to replace only the string that doesn't have other things after it

To do this we can first look for indexOf the intended search string, add the length of the string, then check if the character after it doesn't match a certain set of characters, in which case we set the original string to the substring of the original up until the intended index, then plus the new string, then plus the substring of the original string starting from the length of the search string, to the end. And if the character after the search string DOES match the standard set of characters, do nothing

So let's try to make a function that does that

```
function replaceSpecial(original, search, other, charList) {
    var index= original.indexOf(search)
    if(index > -1) {
         var charAfter = original [index + search.length]
         if (!charList.includes(charAfter)) {
             return original. substring (0, index)  + other + original. substring (index+ search.length)
         } else return original
         
    } else return original
}
```

Then to use it with our example

```
var main ="Hi @jordan123 and @jordan!! have a good day"

var replaced = replaceSpecial (main, "@jordan", "@JordanAnderson", [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```